# How add embedded map to record with sql in OrientDb

Tags: orientdb

I try to add embedded map to record:

```
UPDATE #12:6941 set fieldWithEmbeddedMap ={
    "1": {
        "@type": "d",
        "@version": 0,
        "@class": "myClass",
        "myFiled": "ok"
    },
    "2": {
        "@type": "d",
        "@version": 0,
        "@class": "myClass",
        "myFiled": "ok"
    }
}
```

But result is

```
{"1":"#17:9","2":"#17:10"}
```

What is correct syntax to set embedded field?

Comment: hi zella

does your embedded map need to use  a class?
myClass

Comment: @wolf4ood basically I put map with java `Map<String, ODocument>`, so field inserts correct (it contatins "@class"). I cant update field in studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a class with the property name(string) and fieldWithEmbeddedMap(embeddedMap)

[image]

I have create a record of type Class2

```
insert into class2(name) values ("Alessandro")  // 14:0
```

and after I have used your code

```
UPDATE #14:0 set fieldWithEmbeddedMap ={
    "1": {
        "@type": "d",
        "@version": 0,
        "@class": "myClass",
        "myFiled": "ok"
    },
    "2": {
        "@type": "d",
        "@version": 0,
        "@class": "myClass",
        "myFiled": "ok"
    }
}
```

The result is the following

[image]

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

Java code

```
Map<String, Object> myEntries = new HashMap<String, Object>();
myEntries.put("key1",1);
myEntries.put("key2",2);
myEntries.put("key3",3);

ODocument doc = new ODocument("Test");
doc.field("mymap", myEntries, OType.EMBEDDEDMAP);
doc.save();
```

From Studio

[image]

[image]

Comment: @zella Is this what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Yes, it works. I didn't create any schema, I only inserts documents with `doc.field("fieldWithEmbeddedMap", map, OType.EMBEDDEDMAP);` I am not sure - it is correct that in studio i see field as "embedded", not "embeddedMap" (in no schema mode)?